# Changing some system file values in Android failing

Tags: system

I am trying to change some sys values but I don't seem to be having much success.

In my case I am trying to change values of files in the folder

"/sys/devices/platform/omap/musb-omap2430/musb-hdrc/usb1/1-0:1.0"

e.g. the file bInterfaceClass which currently has value 09

My tries: (In shell, as root)

```
chmod 777 bInterfaceClass
echo 07 >> bInterfaceClass
```

I didn't receive an error but when looking up the value

```
cat bInterfaceClass
```

It is still 09

Now looking up this file in Root Explorer, I can see that the last modification date of the file has changed, so my guess: something resets the value of such a sys file as soon as it changes.

Can anyone shine some more light on this issue?
How can I change the value?